# Есть ли смысл в удалении динамического массива внутри функции?C++

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Есть ли смысл удалять динамический массив, который создаётся внутри функции?
По-моему, после завершения функции она автоматически удалит сам массив, но всё же остается сомнение на этот счёт. Пример кода:

```
void push_face(int *&arr, int &size, const int value)            
{
    int *newArray = new int[size+1];
    for (int i = 1,g=0; i < size+1,g<size+1; i++,g++)
    {
        newArray[i] = arr[g];
    }
    size++;
    newArray[0] = value;
    delete[]arr;
    arr = newArray;
}
```

Есть ли смысл внутри функции удалять newArray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ - единственный: как только массив вам больше не нужен, его нужно удалить. Если нужен - оставить.

В вашей функции вы же зачем-то его возвращаете из функции через `arr`? Значит, он нужен и вне функции? тогда зачем же его удалять?

Другое дело, что потом вы можете просто забыть это сделать - так что ст*о*ит подумать о применении хотя бы идиомы [RAII](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/21603/), если уж не об использовании других типов вместо динамического массива - например, векторов...

> По-моему, после завершения функции она автоматически удалит сам массив

И не подумает. На то и выделение памяти в куче, чтоб она оставалась доступна подольше :)